# Image dimensions for imageView

Tags: java, android

Okay so i have pictures on server. I would like to display them in my app as a part of a ListView row. I've already made that and now I have a question regarding the dimensions of the pictures. Since its a bad idea to save my image at 48dp sizes on server (36x36, 48x48, 72x72, 96x96 ..) and then download specific one for specific DPI device. Is it possible to only save a 96x96 and then set it to an ImageView. ImageView width and width = 48dp, and scaleType= fitCenter. Are there any better ways? please help me

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you need only one image size on a remote server like `96px` and then in Android app just fit it to your needs like `48px`.

The easiest way to implement it would be using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

Of course, there is a [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), with many extra features, (so it might look at the beginnig a bit complicated for beginners), but for the most of uses Picasso is a enough solution.

You can also try a new library developed by Facebook, called [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco),if you care also about memory using but I highly recommend you a Picasso.

Here you would find nice tutorial for this library:
https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

If you would find more information about these three libraries visit this site

[Fragmented Podcast - 005 – Image libraries for Android](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for that. It's very easy to implement.
[Here is a guide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) that explains a little as the two libraries and do what you ask.